# Mongoose Schema Type String not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm updating on my database, but I'm having trouble understanding what is happening with my schema below:

```
{ 
  ref             : String,
  event           : {
    name          : String,
    data          : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    type          : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, // Declaring this as String makes parent(event) undefined. 
  }
}
```

The input data to `event.type` are strings, but when I declare it as such, the `event` field for all existing and new documents become `undefined`.

i.e. in the `Main Function (below)`  I get `Cannot set property 'type' of undefined`

```
// Main function
model
  .find({ 'event.type' : { $exists: false }})
  .exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i<len; i++) {
      data[i].event.type = data[i].ref; // <-- Error Occurs here: Cannot set property 'type' of undefined
      data[i].save()
    }
  })
```

Would love to get some insight. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The property `type` has a special meaning in Mongoose.

If you want to use it as a property name in your schema you need to tell Mongoose to not treat as special:

```
var schema = new Schema({ 
  ref   : String,
  event : {
    name : String,
    data : mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    type : String,
  }
}, { typeKey : '$type' });
```

More info [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey);